# Bug within text editor or front end at all

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-preview

In [a question on Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/216624/2-step-authorization-using-sms-is-less-secure-than-having-2-factor-disabled-at), I've found a possible bug.

The left side of the screenshot is how it looks on the front end of the site, and the right side shows how it looks when editing.

[image: Screenshots of the post when rendered and the post when editing]

You might say that there is a space between braces, but it doesn't matter I think. My point is that there is a difference between the edit preview and the published version.

Comment: looks like the real issue is the preview converts **any url** into a link but this conversion doesn't happen for published posts. You can see this yourself if you change the `[4]` into a `[8]`, the link is still clickable even though 8 is not a valid reference. Not sure if this is a real critical bug.Your `[4]` isn't doing anything to the link before it since there is a space between them as you know.

Comment: The issue still persists. I don't know if it's markdown, CMS or aliens, but there fact is that there is a bug.

Comment: What do you mean by *"at all"* (the title)? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q I understand this as "Is this a bug, at all?" but can't be certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue still persists as of today, however, as mentioned in comments, the bug is only present in the "preview" mode, and that was not considered as a critical bug (thus, there is no estimation if it will addressed or not in the near future). In the meantime, as a workaround, try to change such a tricky post to avoid the discrepancy.

Comment: Modify in what way? Can you provide one or more examples?

Comment: Change in what way, to "avoid the discrepancy"? You didn't really give any answer to @P.Mort. He didn't mean the word itself, so the answer is not complete. I, for one, don't know what to change in order to bypass the bug reported here.